# Wordpress registration with Admin verification

Tags: wordpress, admin, registration

im searching for a way for Wordpress where Users can register themself on the Front-end but need to be verified by an Admin. I have already found some tools, but the Admin verification dont work by me due to an tool that enables closed Usergroups I think. I hope anyone can tell me maybe another way or why it doesn´t work with those tools i already have?

Answer (score 1):

Just use "Theme my login" plugin free from wordpress.org. This plugin will provide you all the functionality which you are searching for. Find this free version of plugin using this link : https://wordpress.org/plugins/theme-my-login

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. I will try it out.

Comment: The Plugin works... excepts the Admin verification Part... if i want to enable the User Moderation it says that it doesnt work with another Plugin named "User Access Manager". Maybe you know another solution? If not im trying not to use the "UAM" Plugin.

Comment: Sorry I dont mean the Plugin "UAM". I mean the feature Multisite (I just overread it^^).